# Camera in landscape is Stretched Android

Tags: android, camera

I have a custom camera that looks good in `Portrait mode` **not stretched** , 
but when the camera is rotated in `Landscape mode` then the Preview is **stretched**

CameraPreview.java

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";
    private static int CAM_ID;

    private Context mContext;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        mCamera = camera;


        // supported preview sizes
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        for (Camera.Size str : mSupportedPreviewSizes)
            Log.e(TAG, str.width + "/" + str.height);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. surfaceChanged will take care of stuff
       setCameraDisplayOrientation();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged => w=" + w + ", h=" + h);
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            //mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            setCameraDisplayOrientation();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }

        float ratio;
        if (mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width)
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.height / (float) mPreviewSize.width;
        else
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.width / (float) mPreviewSize.height;

        // One of these methods should be used, second method squishes preview slightly

//        setMeasuredDimension((int) (width * ratio), height);


        float camHeight = (int) (width * ratio);
        float newCamHeight;
        float newHeightRatio;

        if (camHeight < height) {
            newHeightRatio = (float) height / (float) mPreviewSize.height;
            newCamHeight = (newHeightRatio * camHeight);
            Log.e(TAG, camHeight + " " + height + " " + mPreviewSize.height + " " + newHeightRatio + " " + newCamHeight);
            setMeasuredDimension((int) (width * newHeightRatio), (int) newCamHeight);
            Log.e(TAG, mPreviewSize.width + " | " + mPreviewSize.height + " | ratio - " + ratio + " | H_ratio - " + newHeightRatio + " | A_width - " + (width * newHeightRatio) + " | A_height - " + newCamHeight);
        } else {
            newCamHeight = camHeight;
            setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) newCamHeight);
            Log.e(TAG, mPreviewSize.width + " | " + mPreviewSize.height + " | ratio - " + ratio + " | A_width - " + (width) + " | A_height - " + newCamHeight);
        }
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;

            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        return optimalSize;
    }

    public void setCameraDisplayOrientation() {
        if (mCamera == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "setCameraDisplayOrientation - camera null");
            return;
        }
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(CAM_ID, info);

        WindowManager winManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        int rotation = winManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

        int degrees = 0;

        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
        } else {  // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    }
}
```

Portrait Preview

[image]

Landscape Preview

[image]

Comment: When you call `getOptimalPreviewSize()`, you should swap width and height parameters between portrait and landscape modes.

Comment: I call at onMesaure().

Comment: Note that '(mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width)` never happens

Comment: please help me to solve this . I am stuck in this since yesterday :(

Comment: Actually when I see the three system navigation buttons on the right, I begin to suspect that your device is locked in portrait orientation, and some other logic moves the camera control bottom bar.

Comment: I remove android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" from CameraActvity . still the same problem

Comment: 'configChanges' have nothing to do with this. The device is locked in 'Portrait only', and your Activity does not override this system behaviour. But the question is how the camera control bar is moved.